# Java concurrent access on list with just 1 writer and many objects

Tags: java, list, concurrency

i have the following situation:

I need a list or whatever to store many many objects.

They all are generated by one class that contains the list itself.

Now i have at least one (but perhaps more) classes in other threads that always wanna start with the first object in list and take perodically (20ms-100ms) the next one.

The list is growing by time. At the end there can be up to 300k objects. (one of this objects can contain up to 50 ints or sth like that)

Is the ConcurrentLinkedQueue with own iterator implementation the right way to go?
Own iterator is needed to deny remove option?

Comment: Do you need blocking ? Bounded or unbounded structure?

Comment: Are you saying that the original list can never have elements removed, but can have arbitrary data inserted?

Comment: I think, it's like if a thread is iterating through list then the thread that adds new elements to the list should block.

Comment: Are these classes in other threads removing the objects as they start with them, or is your list just always growing? If they're never being removed, you shouldn't even need to worry about concurrency and just use a regular `ArrayList`.  Otherwise, you do in fact have multiple writers (remove is a write operation).

Answer (score 1):

If you have 1 writer and multiple readers that are iterating through the list as it grows then yes, I would absolutely recommend using the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`.  It is designed for multiple concurrent operations on the queue.

You *cannot* use `Collections.synchronizedList` because the [Javadocs specifically warn](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29) about iterating at modifications to the list:

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned
>   list when iterating over it:

Obviously iterators are the way to go with `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` as the queue gets huge (300k items).  Be careful of `Queue` methods that cause your program to run through the entire queue looking for entries and the like.

Another option to consider is the [`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) available in Java 6+.  Although it is a log2 lookup map, it also has ordered entries so iterating is the same as queue.  This allows you to do map and queue operations on the collection concurrently. Skip-lists++.

*Edit:*

> Own iterator is needed to deny remove option?

If you are asking if you need to override the iterator to not allow removals then yes you do.  You might consider extending the entire `Queue` to return your own custom delegating iterator and to block `Queue.remove(...)` as well.

Comment: down vote OP stated he cannot remove from the Collection.  And the docs of CLQ state they implement all optional functions.

Comment: I don't understand @Woot4Moo.  He's adding to the collection which means modification of it.  I didn't mention removal.  All functions are implemented but look at the javadocs that I mention.  If you are iterating _and_ adding then you have to block.  You can't do both at the same time.

Comment: the docs clearly state that all optional operations are allowed.  `Own iterator is needed to deny remove option?`
Your suggestion is incorrect, because it is clear OP does not want to allow removals.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's only one writer and many readers, you might consider using [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html). From the documentation:

> A thread-safe variant of `ArrayList` in which all mutative operations
>   (add, set, and so on) are implemented by making a fresh copy of the
>   underlying array.
>
> This is ordinarily too costly, but may be more
>   efficient than alternatives when traversal operations vastly outnumber
>   mutations, and is useful when you cannot or don't want to synchronize
>   traversals, yet need to preclude interference among concurrent
>   threads. The "snapshot" style iterator method uses a reference to the
>   state of the array at the point that the iterator was created. This
>   array never changes during the lifetime of the iterator, so
>   interference is impossible and the iterator is guaranteed not to throw
>   `ConcurrentModificationException`.

**Edit:** As Gray points out the sheer number of inserts makes this solution prohibitive - I'd go with his solution.

Comment: 300+k copies?  That's a ton of GC bandwidth to say the least.